# How do I correctly package my extension for compatible Community Editions

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, extensions, package

Lately I have been having an exceedingly difficult time getting my extension approved for Magento Connect. I am packaging using 1.7, and I have followed all the instructions in the Packing Extension Guidelines (as far as I understand them), but my submissions are always returned with the following item for correction:

> Extension Packaging: Repackage your extension correctly so that compatible Community Editions and/or Enterprise Editions correspond with correct channels. (Magento Connect 1.0 and Magento Connect 2.0) Please associate Magento versions 1.5 and above with Magento Connect 2.0 and Magento versions 1.4 and below with Magento Connect 1.0.

I take this to mean that when packaging my extension, the channel value should be aligned to the versions of Magento that I'm targeting ("connect.magentocommerce.com/community" for pre 1.5, and simply "community" for 1.5 and above).  Is that the correct interpretation?

And this is what I have selected during the packaging process:

[image]

However all my submissions come back instructing me to repacking my extension to correspond with the correct channel.  If it's not done in the "Package Info" section, where is that supposed to be done?

**Edit:**  Since my initial posting, I've also tried packaging the extension using CE 1.9.1.0, but have still received the response that my packaging is incorrect.

Comment: when you upload the version to Magento Connect - which versions did you tick?

Comment: I selected versions 1.5 through 1.9

Comment: I don't see an obvious issue with what you've described. Can you upgrade to CE 1.9 to perform the packaging? Perhaps there's some issue with that specific version...

Another idea would be to try to use https://github.com/astorm/MagentoTarToConnect to automate the packaging to minimize any potential manual errors.

Comment: @AdamHobson, thanks for yoru response.  I should have probably edited my question prior to posting the bounty.  Since my initial posting I've tried packaging in 1.9, but unfortunately received the same response.  However, I did not know about Alan Storm's packaging tool, and will try that asap.

Comment: Have you replied to that response you got from Magento and asked them for clarification? That seems to me the best way to go here.

Comment: @JamesAnelay, the responses appear to be form emails with no direct way to respond to them.  I have reached out to them multiple times through their contact form, and have been able to get responses that were more human-like, but still not very helpful  (they essentially just repeat the same message about repackaging).  And, there's also no way for me to directly reply to those messages either :-/

Comment: Ok then in that case you should first fix the License as that should be MIT not MITL, and then I think try installing the package you have just created on a fresh magento install via connect and see if there are issues.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you flush cache files from /var/cache?

Comment: Does your module live in the community or local folder? If local, maybe you should try to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your problem is regarding the package contents and it folder types.
Here is an example of one of my modules output. Just check if your folders corresponds to the correct targets.

[image]

Comment: My extension only contains the modules directory, and the configuration file.  They are both using the correct path.  I even unpackaged the .tgz to confirm that all the files were there.

Answer (score 1):

the issue that reviewer did not see you package on the prereview extension. 
Please check the value of the "Show on front-end" settings on the extension version. Please change it to Yes, so reviewer will have ability to see version on the extension page.